# No sound when running ffmpeg on youtube live

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

Despite my limited knowledge in ffmpeg, I've managed to livestream my birdbox camera to youtube using ffmpeg running on a raspberry pi. The camera has also audio and by using local vlc in windows with rtsp, the audio is ok.

However, on youtube there is no sound (same rtsp command as used locally in windows), and I see this "warning" in youtube studio: "The current bitrate (0) of the audio stream is lower than the recommended bitrate. We recommend using a 128 Kbps bitrate for the audio stream."

How can I get the sound through youtube?
This is the command I run. The command was found on the net, and I adopted it for my usage, and got video working straight away:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -thread_queue_size 512 -rtsp_transport udp -i "rtsp://10.x.x.x:554/user=user&password=password&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream" -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/mykey
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-01-3c740f2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 43.100 / 56. 43.100
  libavcodec     58. 82.100 / 58. 82.100
  libavformat    58. 42.102 / 58. 42.102
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 80.100 /  7. 80.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.1 : mono
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.x.x.x:554/user=user&password=password&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-c:v copy' will be used.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/mykey':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.82.100 aac
[flv @ 0x2c43750] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command is using the anullsrc filter to generate silent audio. YouTube requires an audio stream. So users often use anullsrc to make silent audio to fulfill this requirement if their input has no audio. `ffmpeg` is using this silent audio instead of your camera's audio. Remove anullsrc because you don't need it.

Use:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -rtsp_transport udp -i "rtsp://10.x.x.x:554/user=user&password=password&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/mykey
```

- Because you are [stream copying](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video with `-c:v copy` I removed the unnecessary encoding options that are being ignored anyway (`-tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -pix_fmt`).
- I removed `-strict experimental`. It used to be required when the FFmpeg AAC encoder was considered experimental, but that has not been the case since 2015. However, it is very often still copied and pasted from outdated answers.

Comment: With the new adapted settings (copied directly from the recommendation above), I experience buffering, and see this warning in youtube studio: "YouTube does not receive enough video to maintain consistent streaming. Viewers will therefore experience buffering."
Are the bitrate lowered?

Comment: Youtube studio:  "The current bit rate (1282.17 kbps) is lower than the recommended bit rate. We recommend using a 4500 Kbps bitrate for the stream."

How can I speed up the bitrate? I have 150 Mbps fiber internet, so connection should be ok....

Comment: @Bartonsen It's probably just a warning. YouTube expects a certain bitrate per width x height, but it does mean your stream has to conform to that range. Does the output play fine? If yes, then ignore it. The advantage of using stream copy is that you don't have to re-encode it which may be too much of a task for the Pi anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I really appreciate it.

No, the stream is not ok for long time.
When I start the stream, youtube studio says the quality is excellent, and I confirm that video and audio is perfect.
But after some time (could be 5 mins or 30 mins or 1 hr) youtube-video is buffering or has stopped. ffmpeg is still running on the pi.
In YT studio I see (mixed) warnings like:
"YouTube does not receive enough video to maintain consistent streaming. Viewers will therefore experience buffering."

Comment: or "Your encoder sends data faster than real time (several seconds of video per second). You must limit the live streaming upload rate to approximately one second of video per second."
Could it be the camera? It's a chinese xmeye bird box camera. Streaming locally the sound and video is good.
I have noticed though that the timestamp clock on the camera runs a bit faster/slower than the real world, but there is an option to sync it, which I do now and then, if it has slipped to much...
(It might slip a second or two per 24 hrs.)

Comment: I wanted to post the new ffmpeg output, but this comment field is too small, not sure how to post it
Is there a way to stream at a fixed bitrate?
The pi is a 3B with 1GB RAM, and ffmpeg is using 15% cpu. The pi is not running any other big tasks.

Comment: @Bartonsen You can always edit your question to include new information. You can try re-encoding: `ffmpeg -i rtsp://... -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 8000k -g 40 -preset ultrafast -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -f flv output` If it works good then use the slowest [preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset) that still keeps up with the frame rate. If it is still too slow with ultrafast then re-compile `ffmpeg` with `--enable-omx-rpi` and use `-c:v h264_omx` instead of  `-c:v libx264`.

Comment: Is the ffmpeg installed correctly?
This is what I installed::

cd ffmpeg

./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-omx-rpi

make -j4

sudo make install

Comment: @Bartonsen I suggest asking a new question. My answer directly addressed the question "No sound when running ffmpeg on youtube live". These new issues should be new questions.